# Evaluating $\int_0^{\large\frac{\pi}{4}} \log\left( \cos x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x $

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, definite-integrals, logarithms

It's my first  post here  and I was wondering  if someone  could help me with evaluating the
definite integral 
$$ \int_0^{\Large\frac{\pi}{4}} \log\left( \cos x\right) \, \mathrm{d}x $$
Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try ? maybe putting $t=\cos(x)$ would help

Comment: There is an answer, but I cannot say how it is found: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[Log[Cos[x]]%2C{x%2C0%2CPi%2F4}]

Comment: @Siminore: That link is broken; [here](http://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[Log[Cos[x]]%2C{x%2C0%2CPi%2F4}])'s one that works.

Comment: @Souvik : You mean 'evaluating'.

Answer (score 27):

Let
$$
I=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln(\sin x)\ dx\qquad\text{and}\qquad J=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln(\cos x)\ dx
$$
then
\begin{align}
I+J&=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln(\sin x\cos x)\ dx\\
&=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln\left(\frac12\sin 2x\right)\ dx\\
&=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln(\sin 2x)\ dx-\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln2\ dx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(\sin y)\ dy-\frac\pi4\ln2\qquad\color{red}{\Rightarrow}\qquad \text{set}\ y=2x\\
&=-\frac\pi2\ln2
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
I-J&=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}\right)\ dx\\
&=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln\left(\tan x\right)\ dx\\
&=\int_0^{1}\frac{\ln t}{1+t^2}\ dt\qquad\color{red}{\Rightarrow}\qquad \text{set}\ t=\tan x\\
&=\int_0^{1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n t^{2n}\ln t\ dt\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^{1} t^{2n}\ln t\ dt\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}\\
&=-G,
\end{align}
where $G$ is [Catalan's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant). Therefore
$$
I=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln(\sin x)\ dx=-\frac12\left(G+\frac\pi2\ln2\right)
$$
and
$$
J=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi4}\ln(\cos x)\ dx=\frac12\left(G-\frac\pi2\ln2\right).
$$

---

**References :**

[$[1]\ \ \displaystyle\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(\sin y)\ dy=\int_0^{\Large\frac\pi2}\ln(\cos y)\ dy=-\frac\pi2\ln2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/690705/123277)

[$[2]\ \ \displaystyle\int_0^1 x^\alpha \ln^k x\ dx=\frac{(-1)^k k!}{(\alpha+1)^{k+1}}, \qquad\text{for }\  k=0,1,2,\ldots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/906113/123277)

Comment: The $n$-index in the Catalan constant must start at $\ \color{#c00000}{0}\ $ instead of 1. You can check it
[at this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant).

Comment: very very very nice! (+1)

Answer (score 24):

Write $$\log(\cos(x))=\log\left(\frac12 e^{ix}(1+e^{-2ix})\right)\\
=-\log 2 + ix +\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}e^{-2ikx}.$$
Then integrate term by term to obtain
$$\int_0^{\pi/4}\log(\cos(x))dx=-\frac{\pi}{4}\log 2 +i\frac{\pi^2}{32}+\frac{i}{2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2}\left[e^{-ik\pi/2}-1\right].$$
The odd terms of the series with $e^{-ik\pi/2}$ give rise to the Catalan constant, and the even terms combine with the other infinite series to cancel the $i\pi^2/32$ term.

Answer (score 8):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\ln\pars{\cos\pars{x}}\,\dd x}
= \int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/4}\ln\pars{-\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x = \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\overbrace{\bracks{%
-\ln\pars{2} - \sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\cos\pars{2kx} \over k}}}^{\dsc{\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}}}\,\dd x
=-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
-\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k}\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2}\cos\pars{2kx}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
-\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k}{\sin\pars{k\pi} - \sin\pars{k\pi/2} \over 2k}
=-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
+\half\sum_{k\ =\ 1}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{k\pi/2} \over k^{2}}
\\[5mm]&=-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
+\half\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{k\pi + \pi/2} \over \pars{2k + 1}^{2}}
=-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
+\half\ \underbrace{\sum_{k\ =\ 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pars{2k + 1}^{2}}}
_{\ds{\mbox{Catalan Constant}\ \dsc{G}}}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large-\,{1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2} + \half\,G}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain $$-\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\sin(\pi k)-\sin(\pi k/2)}{k^2}=\sum_{k\geq1}\frac{\sin(\pi k/2)}{k^2}$$

Comment: Wait never-mind I feel like an idiot. $$\forall k\in\Bbb Z, \sin(\pi k)=0$$

Answer (score 3):

By the Fourier series of ln(cos x (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1070809/732917)), we have
$ \begin{aligned}\ln (\cos x) &=-\ln 2+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \cos (2 n x) \\\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\cos x) d x &=-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \cos 2 n x d x \\&=-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}\left[\frac{\sin 2 n x}{2 n}\right]_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \\&=-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2 n^{2}}\left(\sin \frac{n \pi}{2}\right) \\&=-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2 n+1)^{2}} \\&=-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\frac{G}{2},\end{aligned} \tag*{} $
$\textrm{where G is the Catalan's constant.}$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\cos x =\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}}$ so the integral is equal to $$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log\left(\frac{1+\cos 2x}{2}\right)dx =-\frac{\pi}{8}\log(2)+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\log\left(1+\cos 2x \right) dx$$ substituting $2x=y$ gives us $$\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(1+\cos y) dy$$ which the integral evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/909712/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log1-cos-x-dx) and gives us $$-\frac{\pi}{8}\log(2)+\frac{1}{4}\left(2G-\frac{\pi}{2}\log(2)\right)=2G-\frac{\pi}{4}\log(2)$$

The result is straightforward if we use the generalized clausen function ([see here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function#Integral_evaluations_involving_the_direct_function))
$$\int_0^{\theta} \log(\cos y)dy =\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\pi -2\theta\right)-\theta \log(2)$$ or
$$\int_0^{\theta} \log(1+\cos y)dy=2\operatorname{Cl}_2\left(\pi -\theta \right)-\theta \log(2)$$

Answer (score 0):

The integral:
$$S=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{4}\log(\cos(x))dx=\frac{1}{4}(2C-\pi \log 2)$$
where $C$ is the Catalan constant.

Comment: So Wolfram|Alpha tells us. Can you offer any insight into how this result is obtained?

Comment: Hmhm, I saw that answer with Catalan constant,can there be a more elementary solution without infinite series?

Comment: Use $\cos(x)=\frac{\exp(i\theta)+\exp(-i\theta)}{2}$ and then integrate it.

Comment: The reason the Catalan constant has a special name is that it cannot (as far as we know) be written in terms of more familiar things.

Comment: @ Riccardo: This helps us to find the part with $\pi log(2)$ but how do you find the Catalan constant with that ?