# How can I find $\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot x\,dx$?

Tags: integration

Can $\displaystyle\int_0^{\pi/2}x\cot x\,dx$ be found using elementary functions? If so how could I possibly do it? Is there any other way to calculate above definite integral?

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Answer (score 2):

Using integration by parts, we find that

$$\begin{align}I = \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, x \, \cot{x} &= \left [x \log{\sin{x}} \right ]_0^{\pi/2} - \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, \log{\sin{x}} \\ &= - \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, \log{\sin{x}} \end{align} $$

Note that

$$I = - \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, \log{\cos{x}} $$

so that

$$\begin{align} 2 I &= -\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, \log{\sin{x}} -\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, \log{\cos{x}}\\ &= -\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, \log{(\sin{x} \cos{x})} \\ &= -\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, \log{\frac{\sin{2x}}{2}} \\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \log{2} - \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, \log{\sin{2 x}}\\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \log{2} - \frac12 \int_0^{\pi} du \, \log{\sin{u}}\\ &= \frac{\pi}{2} \log{2} + I\end{align} $$

Therefore,

$$I = \int_0^{\pi/2} dx \, x \, \cot{x} = \frac{\pi}{2} \log{2} $$

Answer (score 2):

Using the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma, one can show that $$ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \cot (x) \ dx = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \sin(2nx) \ dx$$

Then $$\int^{\pi /2}_{0} x \cot(x) \ dx = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi /2} x \sin(2nx) \ dx$$

$$ = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \Big( \frac{\sin(2nx)}{4n^{2}} - \frac{x}{2n} \cos(2nx) \Big|^{\pi/2}_{0} \Big)$$

$$ = -\frac{\pi}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n} = \frac{\pi \ln 2}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cot\pars{x}\,\dd x&=
\overbrace{\left.x\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\right\vert_{0}^{\pi/2}}^{\ds{0}}\
-\
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-\,\half\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
+ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{{\pi \over 2} - x}}\,\dd x}
\\[3mm]&=-\,\half\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{2x} \over 2}\,\dd x
=-\,{1 \over 4}\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
+ {1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
\\[3mm]&=-\,{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\ln\pars{\sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
+ {1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
=\half\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cot\pars{x}\,\dd x + {1 \over 4}\,\pi\ln\pars{2}
\end{align}
$$
\color{#00f}{\large\int_{0}^{\pi/2}x\cot\pars{x}\,\dd x = \half\,\pi\ln\pars{2}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation}
\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}x\cot xdx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}xd\ln(\sin(x))=xd\ln(\sin(x))\bigg|^\frac{\pi}{2}_0-\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\ln(\sin(x))dx\\
=\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2
\end{equation}
For the last step, see [Last Step](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosxdx/690693#690693).