# Evaluate $\int_0^4 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}} \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> **Evaluate**
>   $$\displaystyle\int_0^4 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}} \,\mathrm dx$$

How do I evaluate this integral?  I know that the result is $0$, but I don't know how to obtain this.  Wolfram|Alpha yields a non-elementary antiderivative for the indefinite integral, so I don't think I can directly integrate and then plug in the upper/lower limits.

Comment: Wolfram's integrator gives a non elementary primitive.

Comment: @ajotatxe The answer to this is 0 , but I don't know how to get it

Comment: \begin{align}
\int^4_0\frac{\ln{x}}{\sqrt{x(4-x)}}{\rm d}x
=&\int^1_0\frac{2\ln{2}+\ln{x}}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}{\rm d}x\\
=&2\pi\ln{2}+\pi(-\gamma-2\ln{2}+\gamma)\\
=&0
\end{align}

Comment: Try Subsituting $$u=\frac{x}{4}$$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First let $t = x-2$ this way $4x-x^2 = 4 - (x-2)^2 = 4-t^2$. Substitute, 
$$ \int_{-2}^2 \frac{\log(t+2)}{\sqrt{4-t^2}} ~ dt $$
Now let, $\theta = \sin^{-1}\tfrac{t}{2}$ so that $2\sin \theta = t$ and hence, after substitute, 
$$ \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{\log [2(1+\sin \theta)]}{2\cos \theta} 2\cos \theta ~ d\theta = \pi \log 2 + \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \log(1+\sin \theta)~d\theta  $$
To solve this integral, replace $\theta$ by $-\theta$,
$$ I = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \log(1+\sin \theta) ~d\theta= \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \log(1-\sin \theta)~d\theta$$
Now, 
$$ I + I = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \log(1-\sin^2 \theta) ~ d\theta = 4\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \log (\cos \theta) ~ d\theta$$
The last integral is a well-known integral that computes to $-\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2$.

Your final answer is, $\pi \log 2 -\pi\log 2$.

Answer (score 22):

This integral appeared on an 1886 exam at the University of Cambridge and also discussed in *A Treatise on the Integral Calculus* by Joseph Edwards. In general we have

> $$\int_0^a \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\pi\ln\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)$$

**Proof :**

\begin{align}
\int_0^a \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln a+\ln t}{\sqrt{t}\;\sqrt{1-t}}\,\mathrm dt\tag1\\[7pt]
&=\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\ln a+\ln\sin^2\theta }{\sqrt{\sin^2\theta}\;\sqrt{1-\sin^2\theta}}\cdot2\sin\theta\cos\theta\;\mathrm d\theta\tag2\\[7pt]
&=2\ln a\int_0^{\pi/2}\;\mathrm d\theta+4\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin\theta\;\mathrm d\theta\tag3\\[7pt]
&=\pi\ln a-2\pi\ln2\\[7pt]
&=\bbox[5pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\large\pi\ln\left(\frac{a}{4}\right)}}\tag{$\color{red}{❤}$}
\end{align}
Hence
$$\int_0^4 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\bbox[5pt,border:3px #FF69B4 solid]{\color{red}{\large0}}$$

---

**Explanation :**
$(1)\;$ Use substitution $\;\displaystyle x=at$
$(2)\;$ Use substitution $\;\displaystyle t=\sin^2\theta\quad\implies\quad dt=2\sin\theta\cos\theta\;\mathrm d\theta$
$(3)\;$ Use Euler log-sine integral [$\;\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln\sin\theta\;\mathrm d\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/690644/146687)

Comment: @MathGod Thank you ^^

Answer (score 14):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{}$
\begin{align}&\color{#99f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{4}{\ln\pars{x} \over \root{4x - x^{2}}}\,\dd x}
=\int_{0}^{4}{\ln\pars{4\bracks{x/4}} \over \root{x/4 - \bracks{x/4}^{2}}}
\,{\dd x \over 4}
=\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{4x} \over \root{x - x^{2}}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=2\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{4x}^{-1/2}\,\ln\pars{4x}\pars{1- x}^{-1/2}}\,\dd x
=2\lim_{\mu\ \to\ -1/2}\,\,\,\partiald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{4x}^{\mu}\pars{1- x}^{-1/2}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=2\lim_{\mu\ \to\ -1/2}\,\,\,\partiald{}{\mu}\bracks{%
4^{\mu}\,{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{\mu + 3/2}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large 0}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{0}^{4}\frac{\ln{x}}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}dx$

$=\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{\ln{(t+2)}}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}dt$

$=\frac12\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{\ln{(t+2)}}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}dt
+\frac12\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{\ln{(-t+2)}}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}dt$

$=\frac12\int_{-2}^{2}\frac{\ln{(4-t^2)}}{\sqrt{4-t^2}}dt$

$=0$