# Prove that $\int_0^4 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx=0$ (without trigonometric substitution)

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The integral is from P. Nahin's "Inside Interesting Integrals...", problem C2.1. His proposed solution includes trigonometric substitution and the use of log-sine integral.

However, I think the problem should have an easier solution (without appealing to another complicated integral at least).

I have the following trick in mind. Let's introduce the substitution $x=4-z$

$$I=\int_0^4 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx=\int_0^4 \frac{\ln (4-z)}{\sqrt{4z-z^2}}~d(4-z)=\int_0^4 \frac{\ln (4-z)}{\sqrt{4z-z^2}}~dz$$

$$2I=\int_0^4 \frac{\ln (4x-x^2)}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx$$

$$I=\int_0^4 \frac{\ln \sqrt{4x-x^2}}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx$$

---

And here I'm stuck. I'm not sure if this can go somewhere. Maybe partial integration can help, but I don't know how to choose the functions. What do you think?

---

Here is [a question about this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066006/evaluate-int-04-frac-ln-x-sqrt4x-x2-mathrm-dx?rq=1).

Only [one answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1078278/269624) does not use trig substitution, it used gamma function instead. If there are no other ways, I'm prepared to give up on my question. But I would be grateful if it's left open at least for several days

---

**Edit**

After many attempts, I conclude that there is no trick to this integral. The reason is: the general form of this integral in not zero, but has the same symmetry properties, as the above case:

$$I(a)=\int_0^a \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}~dx=\int_0^a \frac{\ln (a-x)}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}~dx=\int_0^a \frac{\ln \sqrt{ax-x^2}}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}~dx \neq 0$$

$$I(4)=0$$

*So we will get nothing from symmetry considerations alone.* There are two possible ways to solve this - either trigonometric substitution or gamma function.

**Edit 2**

I was wrong it seems, see the accepted answer.

Comment: What makes you think there's an easier solution ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I want it to exist

Comment: See wolframalpha gives very hard solution are you surr

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Notice that by the substitution $x = 2 + u$,

$$ I = \int_{-2}^{2} \frac{\log(2 + u)}{\sqrt{4 - u^2}} \, du = \int_{0}^{2} \frac{\log(4 - u^2)}{\sqrt{4 - u^2}} \, du. $$

On the other hand, by the substitution $x = 4 - v^2$ (or equivalently $v = \sqrt{4 - x}$), we have

$$ I = \int_{0}^{2} \frac{\log(4 - v^2)}{v \sqrt{4 - v^2}} \cdot 2v \, dv = 2 \int_{0}^{2} \frac{\log(4 - v^2)}{\sqrt{4 - v^2}} \, dv. $$

Comparing two formulas give $I = 2I$ and therefore $I = 0$.

Comment: Very nice. thank you.

Comment: I gave up too soon. Thank you for this. I guess sometimes it's enough to believe there is a simple solution

Comment: Daaammmmmnnnnn that was nice!

Comment: You also need to show that the integrals involved converge.  [Since $I=\infty$ would satisfy $I=2I$.]

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle K=\int_0^4 \dfrac{\ln (4x-x^2)}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx$

$\displaystyle K=\int_0^4 \dfrac{\ln (4-x)}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx+\int_0^4 \dfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx$

By the change of variable $y=4-x$, it's readily seen that the two preceding integrals are equal.

$\displaystyle K=\int_0^2 \dfrac{\ln (4x-x^2)}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx+\int_2^4 \dfrac{\ln (4x-x^2)}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx$

Perform the change of variable $y=\sqrt{4x-x^2}$ in both preceding integrals,

$\displaystyle K=2\int_0^2 \dfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx+2\int_0^2 \dfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx=4\int_0^2 \dfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4-x^2}}dx$

Thus,

$\displaystyle K=2\int_0^2 \dfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{1-\left(\tfrac{x}{2}\right)^2}}dx$

Perform the change of variable $y=\dfrac{x}{2}$,

$\displaystyle K=4\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln(2x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

$\displaystyle K=4\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln 2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx+4\int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Perform the change of variable $x=\sin y$ in both integrals,

$\displaystyle K=4\ln(2) \int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\cos y}{\sqrt{1-(\sin y)^2}}dy+4\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\ln (\sin y)\cos y}{\sqrt{1-(\sin y)^2}}dy=2\pi\ln 2+4\int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin y)dy$

It is well known that $\displaystyle \int_0^{\tfrac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin y)dy=-\dfrac{\pi \log 2}{2}$

Thus, $K=0.$

Finally we get:

$\displaystyle \int_0^4 \dfrac{\ln (4-x)}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx=\int_0^4 \dfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx=0$

PS:
To be compliant with the question.

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^1 x^{\tfrac{1}{2}-1}(1-x)^{\tfrac{1}{2}-1}dx=\dfrac{\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^2}{\Gamma(1)}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \dfrac{\ln x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s}\left[\int_0^1 x^s(1-x)^{\tfrac{1}{2}-1}dx\right]_{s=-\tfrac{1}{2}}=\dfrac{1}{4}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial s}\left[\dfrac{\Gamma(s+1)\Gamma\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(s+1+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)}\right]_{s=-\tfrac{1}{2}}=-\dfrac{\pi\ln2}{2}$

Comment: Your first link contains already a solution to your question the way you want. ( Felix Marin (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/85343/felix-marin), Evaluate $\int_0^4 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}} \,\mathrm dx$, URL (version: 2015-01-19): http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1078278 )

Comment: I know. At first I wanted there to be a simple solution, now I know that there is no such thing. Thank you for the answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

sketch: put $\sqrt{4x-x^2}=\sqrt{x(4-x)}=xr(t)$,$r(t)$ to be determined. On squaring we get $4-x=xr^2(t)$, thereby $x$ is a rational function of $t$ when $r(t)=\sqrt{t}$. This way we have got rid of the radical. The rest can be dealt with through inrtegration by parts.

Comment: $\int_0^4=\int_0^2+\int_2^4$ and use in both integrals the change of variable $y=\sqrt{4x-x^2}$. The result seems more doable.

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide a generalization of @SangchulLee method for the integral:

$$I(a)=\int_0^a \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}~dx=\int_0^a \frac{\ln (a-x)}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}~dx=\int_0^a \frac{\ln \sqrt{ax-x^2}}{\sqrt{ax-x^2}}~dx$$

Let's make a change of variable:

$$x=\frac{a}{2}+u~~~~~~~a-x=\frac{a}{2}-u$$

$$I(a)=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \frac{\ln (\frac{a^2}{4}-u^2)}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}-u^2}}~du=\int_{0}^{a/2} \frac{\ln (\frac{a^2}{4}-u^2)}{\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}-u^2}}~du$$

Let's make another change of variable:

$$x=a-v^2~~~~~~~a-x=v^2$$

$$I(a)=2 \int_{0}^{\sqrt{a}} \frac{\ln (a-v^2)}{\sqrt{a-v^2}}~dv$$

---

$$I(4)=2 I(4),~~~~~~I(4)=0 $$

However, we can make even more general conclusion. Let's denote $b=a/2$ and:

$$J(b)=\int_{0}^{b} \frac{\ln (b^2-t^2)}{\sqrt{b^2-t^2}}~dt$$

$$J(b)=2 J(\sqrt{2 b})$$

I already know the answer of course, but it it possible to guess:

$$J(b)=C_1 \ln (C_2 b)$$

$$C_1 \ln (C_2 b)=2 C_1 \ln (C_2 \sqrt{2 b})$$

$$C_1 \ln (C_2)+C_1 \ln (b)=2 C_1 \ln (C_2)+C_1 \ln (2)+C_1 \ln (b)$$

$$C_2=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$J(b)=C_1 \ln \left( \frac{b}{2} \right)$$

Which is correct and we only need to find one constant to complete the solution. Which of course requires solving the integral the 'honest' way.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^4 \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{4x-x^2}}~dx\\
&\overset{u=4-x}=\int_0^4 \frac{\ln(4-u)}{\sqrt{u(4-u}}~du\\
2J&\overset{z=\sqrt{\frac{u}{4-u}}}=2\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln\left(\frac{16z^2}{(1+z^2)^2}\right)}{1+z^2}dz\\
&=8\ln 2 \underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{1+z^2}dz}_{=\frac{\pi}{2}}+4\underbrace{\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln z}{1+z^2}dz}_{=0}-4\underbrace{\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(1+z^2)}{1+z^2}dz}_{z=\tan t}\\
&=4\ln 2+8\underbrace{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln(\cos t)dt}_{=-\frac{\pi\ln 2}{2}}=4\ln 2-4\ln 2=0
\end{align}

PS:
The first change of variable is useless. Direct change of variable $u=\sqrt{\frac{x}{4-x}}$ works fine.