# Complex logarithmic integral having Trigonometric function

Tags: definite-integrals

> Finding $\displaystyle \int^{2\pi}_{0}\ln|2\sin(x)+1|dx$

This is what I've tried:

Let $\displaystyle I =\int^{2\pi}_{0}\ln|2\sin(x)+1|dx=\int^{2\pi}_{0}\ln|-2\sin x+1|dx$

$\displaystyle 2I=\int^{2\pi}_{0}\ln|1-2\sin^2(x)|dx=4\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\ln|1-2\sin^2(x)|dx$

Any ideas how to solve it?  Please help!

Comment: This integral is equal to zero.

Comment: may be this is related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3164209/prove-int-02-frac-logx-sqrt4-x2-textdx-0-without-integrating

Comment: @peter Foreman explain me please Thanks

Comment: @jacky Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 2):

Let $I$ denote the integral given by

$$\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{2\pi}\log(|2\sin(x)-1|)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\log(|2\cos(x)-1|)\,dx\tag1
\end{align}$$

---

Enforcing the substitution $z=e^{ix}$ in $(1)$, we find

$$\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
I&=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\log(|z+z^{-1}-1|)}{iz}\,dz\\\\
&=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\log(|z^2-z+1|)-\cancelto{0}{\log(|z|)}}{iz}\,dz\tag2
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as $I$ is purely real and $i\arg(z^2-z+1)$ is purely imaginary, then we must have from $(2)$

$$I=\text{Re}\left(\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\log(z^2-z+1)}{iz}\,dz\right)\tag 3$$

Note that $\frac{\log(z^2-z+1)}{z}$ is analytic in and on the contour $C$ that deforms the unit circle to exclude the branch points with small semi-circular indentations.  The contribution to the value to of the integral from integrating around the indentations vanishes as radii of the semicircular indentations goes to $0$.  Hence, the integral in $(3)$ is $0$ and we are done.