# Integral of $ x \ln( \sin (x))$ from 0 to $ \pi $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> $$\int_0^\pi x \ln(\sin (x))dx  $$

I tried integrating this by parts but I end up getting integral that doesn't converge, which is this $$ \int_0^\pi \dfrac{x^2\cos (x)}{\sin(x)} \ dx$$
So can anyone help me on this one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By making the change of variable
$$
u=\pi -x
$$ you get that
$$
I=\int_0^\pi x \ln(\sin x)\:dx=\int_0^\pi (\pi-u) \ln(\sin u)\:du=\pi\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin u)\:du-I
$$ giving
$$
I=\frac{\pi}2\int_0^\pi \ln(\sin u)\:du=\pi\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin u)\:du.
$$ Then conclude with the classic evaluation of the latter integral: see many answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosxdx).

Comment: Just for my learning, how does the last equality hold? :)

Comment: properties of Definite integral , Odd and even integrals

Comment: The pre-factor of the last integral should be $\pi$ instead of $\pi/4$, no?

Comment: @GDumphart Right, I've divided instead of multiplying... thanks!

Comment: @H.R. Sorry, I did not notice your comment. "How does the last equality hold?", please have a look at this:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosxdx/690705#690705

Comment: @OlivierOloa: Thanks. :)