# How to integrate $\int \ln(\cos^2 x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Integral: $$\int \ln(\cos^2 x) dx$$

I applied **parts** technique twice, first by expressing it as $-2\int1\cdot\ln(\sec x)$, which is

$$I = -2x\ln(\sec x)+2\int x\tan (x)dx$$

Now the second term can be integrated by **parts** to give:

$$I = x\ln(\cos^2 x) + 2\left(x\ln(\sec x)-\int\ln(\sec x)dx\right)$$
But second term of the bracket itself is $\dfrac{I}{2}$, so

$$I = x\ln(\cos^2 x) + 2x\ln(\sec x)+I$$

Now the I cancels out! I am not getting anywhere with this approach.

Comment: $$\log(\cos^2(x))=2\log(\cos(x))=2\log(2)+2\log(e^{ix}+e^{-ix})=
2\log(2)-2ix+2\log(e^{2ix}+1)=\\
2\log(2)-2ix+2\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^ne^{ixn}}{n}$$

also use the defintion of dilogarithm function

Comment: There is a missing minus at the beginning of line three, this explains why they cancel out. You first integrated by parts then undid it.

Comment: The integral of log(cos(x)) has no 'closed form' expression using standard functions. You will need to define it in terms of the series $x^2/n$ from n = 1 to infinity.

Comment: Related definite integral: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/690644/269624

Answer (score 2):

You integral is related with the [inverse tangent integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseTangentIntegral.html) and the dilogarithm function.
The substitutions $x=\arctan t$, $1+t^2=u$, $u=\frac{1}{v}$ bring your integral into
$$ -\int \frac{\log(1+t^2)}{1+t^2}\,dt = -\int \frac{\log(u)\,du}{2u\sqrt{u-1}}=\int \frac{\log(v)\,dv}{\sqrt{v(1-v)}}$$
and the last integral is 
$$ \left.\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int v^{\alpha-\frac{1}{2}}(1-v)^{-1/2}\,dv\,\right|_{\alpha=0^+} $$
i.e. the derivative of an incomplete Beta function.