# Integral with parameter, explicitly defining function F(y)

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

So i have this integral with parameter:
$$F(y)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln{(y^2-\sin^2{x})}dx$$ also let $y>1$

So i want to define function $F(y)$ explicitly.
I know i should use some partial derivatives and using properties of that multivariable function $F(x,y)$ but i don't know what to do after i define it like this:
$$F(x,y)=\ln{(y^2-\sin^2{x})}$$
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You *have* defined $F$ explicitly as an integral. What exactly is it you want to do? (Note you shouldn't call both the integrand and the function defined by the integral $F$ as they are two different functions.)

Comment: @smcc it's suppose to write function without the integral sign, sorry for the confusion but it's stated : " Explicitly write function F(y)"

Comment: Yes, but the function *is* defined explicitly. From your comment, it seems a more accurate statement of your problem would be: "Evaluate the integral $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln{(y^2-\sin^2{x})}dx$, where $y>1$".

Comment: WolframAlpha gives the value of the integral as $\pi\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}+y}{2}\right)$. (The indefinite integral looks quite messy.)

Comment: By symmetry the integral equals $\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{2\pi}\log(y^2-\sin(x)^2)dx$. Now use $z=e^{i x}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(y)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(x,y) dx$. By [Leibnitz-rule](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Leibniz_integral_rule), we have
$$F'(y)=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f'_y(x,y)dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2y}{y^2-\sin^2(x)}dx=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{2y}{y^2-1+\cos^2(x)}dx\stackrel{t=\tan{x}}=\int_0^\infty \frac{2y}{(y^2-1)t^2+y^2}=\int_0^\infty \frac{2}{y((\frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}}{y}t)^2+1)}dt\stackrel{x=\frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}}{y}t}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{y^2-1}}$$

Therefore, $$F(y)=\int \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{y^2-1}} dy=\pi\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}+y}{2}\right)+C.$$

Now, you have to calculate $F(1+)=-\pi\ln{2}$ in order to obtain $C=0$ (I leave this to you as an exercise. You can check your result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosxdx)).

Finally, 
 $$F(y)=\pi\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{y^2-1}+y}{2}\right).$$

Comment: good one (+1)...residue theorem would be also an option

Comment: Derivation wrt $y$ under the integral is not explained.