# Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{1+y^{2}}\log\left(\sqrt{1+y^{2}}+\sqrt{x+y^{2}}\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms

I need help finding an analytical expression for the integral
$$I(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dy}{1+y^{2}}\log\left(\sqrt{1+y^{2}}+\sqrt{x+y^{2}}\right), $$
where $0<x<1$. 
The expression can be written using polylog, elliptic function or any other known integral functions...

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm not super happy with what I have, but I'm posting in case it helps others find a better formula.

$$\boxed{I(x)=\pi\log 2 -\frac 1 2 \int_x^1 \frac{K(\sqrt{1-t})-\frac \pi 2}{1-t}dt=\pi\log 2-\frac {\pi} 4 \sum_{n\geq 1}\left( \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}}$$
where we  identify the [complete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_first_kind) $$K(k)=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1 -k^2\sin^2\theta}}$$
Thre might be a way to get another form using hypergeometric functions, but I couldn't. Anyway, here's what I did:

$$\begin{split}
I^\prime(x)&= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dy}{2(y^2+1)\sqrt{x+y^2}\left(\sqrt{x+y^2}+\sqrt{y^2+1}\right)}\\
&= \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x+y^2}-\sqrt{y^2+1}}{2(y^2+1)\sqrt{x+y^2}(x-1)}dy\\
&=\frac 1 {2(x-1)}\left(\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{y^2+1}dy -  \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{(y^2+1)(x+y^2)}}  \right)\\
&= \frac 1 {2(x-1)}\left(\frac \pi  2 -  \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta + x\sin^2\theta}}   \right) \text { with }\theta=\arctan \frac y {\sqrt x}\\
&=  \frac 1 {2(x-1)}\left(\frac \pi  2 -  \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{1 - (1-x)\sin^2\theta}}   \right)\\
&= \frac 1 {2(x-1)}\left(\frac \pi  2 - K(\sqrt{1-x})\right)
\end{split}$$
Using the power series for $K$, $$K(\sqrt{1-x})=\frac \pi 2 \sum_{n\geq 0}\left( \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2(1-x)^n$$
we obtain
$$\begin{split}
I(x)-I(1)&=\frac {\pi} 4 \sum_{n\geq 1}\left( \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2\int_1^x (1-t)^ndt\\
&=-\frac {\pi} 4 \sum_{n\geq 1}\left( \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}\right)^2\frac{(1-x)^{n+1}}{n+1}
\end{split}$$
Finally
$$\begin{split}
I(1)&=\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\log(2\sqrt{1+y^2})}{1+y^2}dy\\
&=\frac \pi 2 \log 2+\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\log(\sqrt{1+y^2})}{1+y^2}dy\\
&=\frac \pi 2 \log 2-\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\log(\cos \theta)d\theta \\
&= \pi \log 2
\end{split}$$
where we have used [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosx-mathrmdx?noredirect=1&lq=1).