# How to find $\int\log(\cos(a/x))dx$ in closed form or asymptotic estimation?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, asymptotics, improper-integrals, estimation

I was not sure how to go about finding a closed form for $$\int\log\left(\cos\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)\right) \ dx\,\,\,\,(1)$$

so I was wondering if there is some clever integration trick that would work?

(Perhaps using $a$ as an integral upper limit and lower limit $>=0$ might produce some result as a definite integral?)

---

Some work done so far by me...

Trying an asymptotic expansion using a integration by parts with a=1 seems to look like things will get rather complicated quick or at least I cannot see an easily identifieble series emerging for (1) How can one tell in advance? 
$$-\frac{1}{2} x^2 \left(-\frac{2 \tan ^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^3 \log ^3\left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}-\frac{\sec ^2\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^3 \log ^2\left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}-\frac{\tan \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2 \log ^2\left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}\right)+\frac{x}{\log \left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}+\frac{\tan \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\log ^2\left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}+\frac{\tan \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x \log ^2\left(\cos \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)}$$

Comment: What is the original problem you're after? Wasn't there a definite integral or something?

Comment: @zacky After looking at $\int_0^{\pi/2}\log\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690644/evaluate-int-0-pi-2-log-cosx-mathrmdx I wondered if 1/x had been investigated over some range that is why I left any limit out. Also I've removed the second question because it does not help and is a bit of a whale sandwich.

Comment: Well, we have:$$\int \ln\left(\cos\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)\right)dx\overset{\frac{a}{x}=t}=-a\int \frac{\ln \cos t}{t^2}dt\overset{IBP}=\frac{a}t\ln \cos t +a\int \frac{\tan t}{t}dt$$
I suggest to not waste too much effort around it without a specific motivation.

Comment: @zacky okay thank you for reworking it into $\frac{a}t\ln \cos t +a\int \frac{\tan t}{t}dt$.