# Double integral $ \iint \limits_D \frac{y}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dxdy$, $D$=$\{(x,y): x^2+y^2 \le1 , y\ge0\}$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Solve $$ \iint \limits_D  \frac{y}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dxdy \ \ \ \ . . . \  (*)$$
>
> where $D$=$\{$$(x,y): x^2+y^2 \le1 ,  y\ge0       $$\}$

$$
$$
Here is my attempt.

$$\begin{align}
&(1).\ \ \ (*)=\int_{-1}^1  \int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\frac{y}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dydx \\
&(2).\ \ \ (*)= \int_{0}^1  \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{y}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dxdy \\
&(3). \ \ \int\frac{y+1}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dx = \arctan\left(\frac{x}{y+1}\right) + C  \\
&(4). \ \  \ (*)=\int_{0}^{\pi}  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{r^2sin\theta}{r^2+2rsin\theta+1}drd\theta \\\\
\end{align}$$

I used $(1)$, $(4)$ and $(2)$ with $(3)$,

but didn't solve yet.
$$$$
Did I make a mistake?

Could you give me some advice, please?

How can I solve this integral...

Thank you for your attention to this matter.

$$$$
P.S.

Here is **result of wolframalpha**

[image]

[image]

[image]

$$$$

$$ $$
**Additionally... I did like this.. maybe useless :-(**

$$\begin{align}
(*) 
&  = \int_{0}^1  \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{y}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dxdy \\\\
&=\int_{0}^1  \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{y+1}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dxdy + \int_{0}^1  \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{1}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dxdy \\\\
&=\int_{0}^1  \left(\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y+1}\right) - \arctan\left(\frac{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y+1}\right)\right)dy \\ 
& \ \ \ \ + \int_{0}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{1}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dxdy  \\\\
&=\int_{0}^1  \left(\arctan\left(\sqrt\frac{1-y}{1+y} \ \right) - \arctan\left(-\sqrt\frac{1-y}{1+y} \ \right)\right)dy \\
& \ \ \ \ +\int_{0}^1 \int_{-\sqrt{1-y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\frac{1}{x^2+(y+1)^2}dxdy \\\\
&= terrible?!   \\
\end{align}$$

$$
$$

$$ $$
**---------------------------------------------------------------------------**

This picture is for asking to **Christian Blatter**

(I am really sorry, if I bother you guys for this picture.)

[image]

Comment: Which techniques are you supposed to use? If it's an exercise from a comples analysis book, perhaps you may find a way out using [Poisson's integral formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel).

Comment: 'Which techniques'... I have struggled with [Integrals in Polar Coordinates] and [trigonometric substituion]. BUT ... I am struggling now. $$ $$Poisson's int formula, Now I study this. Thanks a lot. $$ $$ And I think THIS PROBLEM is an exercise from CALCULUS.. (well, maybe not.. sorry)

Comment: Why you'd try and solve this problem in Cartesian coordinates AT ALL is beyond me. It still won't be easy,but it's got to be better then this nightmare you've shown!

Comment: That's exactly the figure I had made for myself.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Aha, thank a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I shall introduce new coordinates (again denoted by $x$, $y$) such that the point $(0,-1)$ becomes the origin, and your vertical axis is my horizontal axis. Your integral then appears as
$$J:=\int_H{x-1\over x^2+y^2}\>{\rm d}(x,y)\ ,$$
where $H$ is the right half of the unit disk with center $(1,0)$. Introducing polar coordinates we obtain
$$J=\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\int_{1/\cos\phi}^{2\cos\phi}{r\cos\phi-1\over r^2} r\>dr\ d\phi\ .$$
Here the inner integral evaluates to
$$(2\cos^2\phi-1)-(\log 2+2\log\cos\phi)\ .$$
We therefore get
$$J=1-{\pi\over2}\log 2-4\int_0^{\pi/4}\log\cos\phi\ d\phi=1+{\pi\over2}\log 2-2 \>{\tt Catalan}\doteq0.256862\ ,$$
where ${\tt Catalan}$ is [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) ($\doteq0.915966$)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! But I have some question. Is this right manner, if I modify my question for asking to you?? (I'd like to upload a picture..)

Comment: @user143993: When something is unclear in my answer, ask in a comment to it. For supplementary problems  I suggest you update your question.

Comment: I update my question. Could you answer my question, please? Really thank you.

Comment: and I'd (REALLY) like to know 'thinking process' for making $J$ (you have defined)

Comment: $$$$ I'd REALLY like to know your 'thinking process' for making J (you have defined). Id est, what make you think this "NEW region H" from "the origin region D"??

Comment: Excellent solution,but I think you took it further then the OP was really required to. It's hard to imagine a basic calculus student being able to do this kind of heavy duty computation unless it's an honors course. And even then.

Answer (score 4):

The integrand function $\frac{y}{x^2+(y+1)^2}$ suggest to put
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
x&=r\cos\theta\\
y+1&=r\sin\theta
\end{align}\right.
$$
so that $x^2+(y+1)^2=r^2$ and the Jacobian is $r$.

From $y\ge 0$ we have $y=r\sin\theta-1\ge 0$ that is $r\ge\frac{1}{\sin\theta}$ and from $x^2+y^2\le 1$ we have $$x^2+y^2=r^2\cos^2\theta+(r\sin\theta-1)^2=r^2-2r\sin\theta+1\le 1$$ and then $r(r-2\sin\theta)\le0$ so that $r\le 2\sin\theta$.
So we have
$$\boxed{
r_{\min}=\frac{1}{\sin\theta}\le r\le 2\sin\theta=r_{\max}}
$$
For $y=0$ (i.e. $r\sin\theta =1$) we have $-1\le x\le 1$, that is $-1\le r\cos\theta\le 1$ and then $-1\le\tan\theta\le 1$; thus
$$\boxed{
\theta_{\min}=\frac{\pi}{4}\le \theta\le \frac{3\pi}{4}=\theta_{\max}}
$$

or $\frac{-\pi}{4}\le \theta\le \frac{+\pi}{4}$ if you prefer.

The figure help to show all we have done.
[image]

So the integrand in polar coordinates becomes $f(r,\theta)=\frac{r\sin\theta-1}{r^2}$ and the integral becomes
$$
\mathcal{I}=\int_{\theta_{\min}}^{\theta_{\max}}\int_{r_{\min}}^{r_{\max}}
f(r,\theta)r\,\mathrm d r\,\mathrm d\theta=
\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sin\theta}}^{2\sin\theta}\left(\sin\theta-\frac{1}{r}\right) \mathrm d r\,\mathrm d\theta
$$
The integral in $r$ is easy to evaluate
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\frac{1}{\sin\theta}}^{2\sin\theta}\left(\sin\theta-\frac{1}{r}\right) \mathrm d r
&=
\left[\sin\theta\, r-\log r\right]_{\frac{1}{\sin\theta}}^{2\sin\theta}\\
&=\sin\theta\left[2\sin\theta-\tfrac{1}{\sin\theta}\right]-\left[\log(2\sin\theta)-\log\left(\tfrac{1}{\sin\theta}\right)\right]\\
&=-\cos(2\theta)-\log\left(2\sin^2\theta\right)
\end{align}
$$
Then the integral in $\theta$ is
$$\begin{align}
\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} \left[-\cos(2\theta)-\log\left(2\sin^2\theta\right)\right]\mathrm d \theta
&=
\left[-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\theta)\, \right]_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}-\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} \log\left(2\sin^2\theta\right)\mathrm d \theta=1+J
\end{align}
$$
where
$$
J=-\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} \log\left(2\right)\mathrm d \theta-\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} \log\left(\sin^2\theta\right)\mathrm d \theta=
-\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2-2C+\pi\log 2=\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2-2C
$$
observig that 
$$\begin{align}
-\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3\pi}{4}} \log\left(\sin^2\theta\right)\mathrm d \theta &=
-\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \log\left(\cos^2\theta\right)\mathrm d \theta=-2\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \log\left(\cos^2\theta\right)\mathrm d \theta\\
&=-4\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \log\left(\cos\theta\right)\mathrm d \theta=-4\left(\frac{C}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}\log 2\right)\\
&=-2C+\pi\log 2
\end{align}
$$
where $C$ is the [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant) (see for exaple [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199094/evaluating-int-0-large-frac-pi4-log-left-cos-x-right-mathrmdx/917086#917086)).

Finally we have
$$\large\color{blue}{
\mathcal I=1+\frac{\pi}{2}\log 2-2C}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Really nice :-)