# Double integral of $1/(x^2+y^2)$ restricted to $x^2+y^2\leq2$ and $x\leq1$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, bounds-of-integration

> Find $$\iint_D \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dA$$ where $$D = \left\{ (x,y): x^2 + y^2 \leq 2 \right\} \cap \left\{ (x,y): x \geq 1 \right\}$$

---

Because of the prevalence of $x^2+y^2$ terms here, I figured we would be using a change of variables to polar coordinates with $dA = rdrd\theta$. However, I ran into trouble when finding the bounds of the integral. I know $r$ goes from $0$ to $\sqrt 2$, but I got stumped when considering $\theta$. Solving for $\theta$ using the substitution $x=r\cos\theta$ into $x\leq 1$, I got $\theta =\arccos(\frac{1}{r})$. This seems ok, but it resulted in an integral that is impossible to solve by hand (maybe not technically impossible, but clearly I did something wrong here).

I also don't think using Cartesian coordinates would be the right approach, since the polar coordinate substitution results in very nice cancelling and easy integration.

Comment: $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$, but the range of $r$ depends on $\theta$, as $D$ is a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment).

Comment: The title says $x\leq1$, the body says $x\geq1$. Which one is intended?

Comment: There's also a missing $^2$ in the title.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear: the title and the body of the question don't match, and so far there are two answer based on two different hypotheses on what the question really is. You have to settle this.

Answer (score 1):

Make the limits of $r$ a function of $\theta$.

$x = 1$ corresponds to $\theta = \pm \dfrac{\pi}{4} $

So for the interval $\theta \in [- \dfrac{\pi}{4}, \dfrac{\pi}{4} ] $ the limits for $r$ are $0$ and $\sec \theta$, otherwise, the limits are $0, \sqrt{2}$

Thus, the integral becomes

$$ I = \displaystyle \large\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \int_0^{\sec(\theta)} \dfrac{1}{r^2} r dr d\theta + \int_\frac{\pi}{4}^{\frac{7\pi}{4}} \int_1^\sqrt{2}\dfrac{1}{r^2} r dr d\theta $$

Comment: There is still an integral $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\log\cos\theta\;\mathrm d\theta$, for which there is a derivation here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199094/evaluating-int-0-large-frac-pi4-log-left-cos-x-right-mathrmdx?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

In polar coordinates, the area is enclosed by
$$r=\sqrt2,\>\>\>\>\> r\cos\theta =1$$
Eliminate $r$ to get $\cos \theta =\frac1{\sqrt2}$, i.e. $\theta \in (-\frac\pi4, \frac\pi4)$. Therefore, the ares is integrated as
$$A=\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4}\int_\frac1{\cos \theta}^\sqrt2
\frac1{r^4}rdr d\theta=\frac14\int_{-\frac\pi4}^{\frac\pi4}
\cos2\theta\>d\theta=\frac14
$$